# How to display Entity property in jsp

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jsp-tags

I need to display in JSP datastore query result. I get data and forward them into JSP file:

```
    Query query = new Query("oAuth", key);
    List<Entity> users = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));

    try {
        // Set the attribute and Forward to hello.jsp
        req.setAttribute ("users", users); // to save your temporary calculations. 
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/sharemarkerusers.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

Here is the content of my jsp file

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> 

<html>
  <body>
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.userEmail}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I got result: Could not find property userEmail in class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity

Well when I display in the cell just user variable, it actually displays:

```
<html>

  <body>

    <table>



            <tr>

                <td><Entity [oAuth("******")/oAuth("*********")]: 
    accessToken = *********** 
    accessTokenSecret = ************ 
    userEmail = usersemail@example.com 
> 
</td>

            </tr>



    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

So the question is, hou I can access the property of entity via ${user.?} tag? forEach loops at it should.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The JSP EL is used to access JavaBean properties. This means that `${user.userEmail}` looks for a getter `getUserEmail()` in the attribute `user`.

You will have to transform your entities into JavaBeans, or use custom tags to access Entity properties.

Also, not that you should use `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml` to display properties which potentially contain HTML special chars, and/or are submitted by end users. Not doing so exposes your app to XSS attacks, and will potentially generate broken HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Try with ${user.properties.userEmail}